# Movie with the humanoid aliens with inverted legs (knees bent backwards)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't remember the storyline too well, it's been way too long since I've seen the movie.

All I remember is the aliens are **very humanoid** but have **inverted legs i.e. their knees bend backwards.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[*The Arrival*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115571/) (1996) is probably the movie you're looking for. The aliens had a "skin suit" of sorts that covered their bodies to make them look human, and they had the ability to walk with their legs bent either forward or backward.

> When the astronomer Zane Zaminski receives signal from a distant star, he reports and gives all the evidences to his chief, Phil Gordian, and is immediately fired. Zane becomes obsessed to locate the signals again and finds a transmission to the outer space in the same wave from Mexico, and he flies to the place. Meanwhile, the scientist Ilana Green is investigating the unexplained raise of the temperature in Third World countries and also goes to Mexico for further research.

Answer (score 8):

Is this "The Arrival" starring 'Winning' Charlie Sheen? The plot is about aliens who disguised as humans cause global warming to wipe out humans as they need a hot planet to live on.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Arrival_(film))