# Low budget alien movie about the Earth being cooked

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I’m looking for an alien movie I watched years ago, mid to late 2000’s about the Earth being cooked or heated up by aliens. The poster is a reflection of the Earth heating up with an orange glow on an aliens eye. It was a low budget movie and I think the one I watched was pirated from China. Again low budget, bad quality and the name could’ve been something worthy he word scorch or something like that. The alien in the movie had legs with knees that went inwards and it had red eyes.

Comment: An Inconvenient Truth

Comment: An Inconvenient Truth: A History Channel Movie

Comment: Please use the green checkbox to accept any correct answers you have received.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34445/what-is-the-movie-with-the-humanoid-aliens-with-inverted-legs

Answer (score 19):

## [*The Arrival*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115571/) (1996)

In it aliens are found to be releasing greenhouse gases into the atmosphere to heat up Earth in order to kill off humanity.

> Zane discovers the plant doubles as a front for an underground alien base. The very different looking aliens are able to disguise themselves with an external skin to infiltrate human society. Zane finds that all of the bases expel large amounts of greenhouse gas into the atmosphere. Zane is discovered but escapes back into the nearby town and attempts to convince the local sheriff of the situation. However, alien agents bring Ilana's body to the police station, making Zane a suspect in her death; Zane escapes and sneaks back into the United States. He accosts Phil on the JPL grounds, forcing him to admit that the aliens are trying to raise the Earth's temperature to not only kill off humans (by greatly exacerbating anthropogenic climate change) but to make the planet hospitable for themselves. Zane secretly records the conversation and once Phil discovers the recording he sends agents to stop Zane.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *The Arrival* (1996 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Arrival_(1996_film))</sub>

The Wikipedia summary also mentions the legs that bend backwards:

> they watch as Kiki's legs form into a shape similar to that of backward kangaroo legs, then runs off.

And if this image is correct they look something like this:

[image: The Arrival alien]

The poster doesn't match exactly match what you say but there is the reflection in the eyes and the orange glow. I believe there are different variants of this with the objects at different perspectives but the general theme is the same.

[image: The Arrival movie poster]

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons ;-)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if Charlie Sheen remembers any part of making this movie. Just judging by his appearance in the film it seems like a particularly **"WINNING"** time in his life.

Comment: Not to be confused with *Arrival* (2016), starring Amy Adams, which is a **much** bet-- I mean different movie.

Comment: Weird. That poster reminds me of a laser disk "container", which was seemingly about a man who switched face with someone else. The picture depicted the 2 half of the faces, one on each size, almost like that.

Comment: I actually liked The Arrival much better than Arrival.  I was bored during Arrival, and disappointed with the ending.